# What is the effect of "*" in regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

My Java source code:

```
String result = "B123".replaceAll("B*","e");
System.out.println(result);
```

The output is:`ee1e2e3e`.
Why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

'*' means zero or more matches of the previous character. So each empty string will be replaced with an "e".

You probably want to use '+' instead:

> `replaceAll("B+", "e")`

Comment: 99% right...it's a greedy search, so if it can match "B", it will.  
Otherwise, the output would've been "eee1e2e3e"

Comment: The ':' is probably a copy-paste error, the supplied code cannot produce a ':' ...

Comment: I don't think the : was meant to be construed as part of the output.

Comment: Where are the empty string?like this: " B 1 2 3 "?

Comment: The regexp parser will go through your string character by character. At position 0 it will replace 'B' with 'e', at position 1 it will replace '' with 'e', and so on.

Comment: Yes, the empty strings are between each character, and at the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 7):

You want this for your pattern:

```
B+
```

And your code would be:

```
String result = "B123".replaceAll("B+","e");
System.out.println(result);
```

The "*" matches "zero or more" - and "zero" includes the nothing that's before the B, as well as between all the other characters.

Comment: On the first attempt the regex consumes the 'B', not an empty string. Then it matches the empty string at each position, starting at the position where the first match left off.

Answer (score 1):

I spent over a month working at a big tech company fixing a bug with * (splat!) in regular expressions.  We maintained a little-known UNIX OS.  My head nearly exploded because it matches ZERO occurrences of an encounter with a character.  Talk about a hard bug to understand through your own recreates.  We were double substituting in some cases.  I couldn't figure out why the code was wrong, but was able to add code that caught the special (wrong) case and prevented double subbing and didn't break any of the utilities that included it (including sed and awk).  I was proud to have fixed this bug, but as already mentioned.

For god's sake, just use **+** !!!!

Comment: Yeah, that double match thing is pretty bizarre. It threw me a few times before I learned to watch for it. And a +1 for always using + instead of * if you can.